# UTF-8 encoding, dictionary look-up

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I have written a web-scraper using Scrapy, grabbing some data to complementing my current information I have about a couple of companies. Before I print out the records I want to match them against my old records. Hence, I have created a dictionary with a company name as key and values are some related data. The problem I have is with the encoding, the Test_of_company.csv is encoded in UTF-8 (I encoded it and converted it to UTF-8 in notepad++). I keep getting the exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 67: invalid continuation byte. Since the **accumulator** contains UTF-8 encoding and **check** has a different encoding, I cannot match up the records. In general I think encoding is a hassle in python-2.7.

**pipeline file in scrapy project**

```
class DomainPipeline(object):
    accumulator = collections.defaultdict(list)
    check=collections.defaultdict(list)
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        output="{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}".format(item['founded'],item['employee3'],item['employee2'],item['employee1'],item['rev3'],item['rev2'],item['rev1'])
        self.accumulator[item['company']].append(output)
        return item

    def close_spider(self,spider):
        root = os.getcwd()
        p = os.path.join(root, 'Company_Lists', 'Test_of_company.csv')
        with codecs.open(p,'r','utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                field = line.split(',')
                company=str(field[1])
                self.check[company.strip()].append(line)

        file = open('output.txt','w')
        for company,record in self.check.items():
            for person in record: 
                for info in self.accumulator[company]:
                    output="{0},{1}\n".format(person.strip(),info)
                    file.write(output)
```

**Log file**

```
2014-02-09 17:47:27+0000 [AllaBolag] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-02-09 17:47:27+0000 [AllaBolag] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 59, in _process_parallel
        return process_parallel(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 84, in process_parallel
        dfds = [defer.succeed(input).addCallback(x, *a, **kw) for x in callbacks]
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 306, in addCallback
        callbackKeywords=kw)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 295, in addCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "Autotask_Prospecting\pipelines.py", line 28, in close_spider
        for line in f:
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 684, in next
        return self.reader.next()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 615, in next
        line = self.readline()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 530, in readline
        data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 477, in read
        newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
    exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 67: invalid continuation byte

2014-02-09 17:47:27+0000 [AllaBolag] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 9699,
     'downloader/request_count': 23,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 23,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 618283,
     'downloader/response_count': 23,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 23,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 17, 47, 27, 889000),
     'item_scraped_count': 10,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 39,
     'log_count/ERROR': 3,
     'log_count/INFO': 3,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 23,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 23,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 23,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 23,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 23,
     'spider_exceptions/IndexError': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 17, 47, 25, 428000)}
2014-02-09 17:47:27+0000 [AllaBolag] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace? Also, why are you doing `str(company).strip()` and `str(field[1])`?

Comment: Ah, that was before I figured out it was the encodning that was messing with it. I thought it was a trailing whitespace or something that might have messed with the lookup. what is stacktrace?

Comment: The lines in your console stating what line is in error, and the hierarchy of calls to this line, basically the 10 or 20 lines with the Python exception, to know what line is wrong in your code. It's not obvious in your question.

Comment: Solved it, the encoding for the file was Latin1...

Answer (score 2):

Given the OP already found the answer, I'm going to complement with an useful option to debug any of exception.

Scrapy have a very useful command-line option named `--pdb`:

```
$ scrapy crawl -h
Usage
=====
...


Global Options
--------------
...
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```

For instance, to reproduce your error I use this spider code:

```
# file: myspider.py
# encoding: utf-8
import codecs
import tempfile

from scrapy.spider import Spider


class MyspiderSpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.org/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = self._create_test_file()
        with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                self.log(line)

    def _create_test_file(self):
        fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        fp.write(u'Westfälisch'.encode('latin1'))
        return fp.name
```

Then running the spider with the option `--pdb` starts the [Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) when the exception pops up. Below is an example session that shows how you can find the value that fails, reproduce the exception and find the solution:

```
$ scrapy crawl myspider --pdb
2014-02-10 13:05:53-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.1 started (bot: myproject)
...
2014-02-10 13:05:53-0400 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.org/> (referer: None)
Jumping into debugger for post-mortem of exception ''utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 5: invalid continuation byte':
> /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py(477)read()
-> newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
(Pdb) print data
Westf�lisch
(Pdb) repr(data)
"'Westf\\xe4lisch'"
(Pdb) data.decode('utf8')
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
(Pdb) data.decode('latin1')
u'Westf\xe4lisch'
```